pd.read_csv on Windows vs Linux (local vs Azure Function App)
I have a peculiar issue with reading a csv file from pandas, the file would look something like:
col1    col2    col3\r\n
1   this is a place for some text   50\r\n
2   this is some other \n text  100\r\n
3   and finally \n a bit more \n text   150\r\n

Note that, as a windows standard, the lineterminators are \r\n, while the data sometimes contains \n. The separator between the columns is a tab.
I have a code that looks something like this:
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str(file_content_binary,'utf-8')), sep = '\t', lineterminator = '\r', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

For the most part this works I only need to clean up the extra \n in the first column post-processing, as pd.read_csv doesn't support multi character line terminators. This looks something like so:
data[col1] = data[col1].str.lstrip('\n')
data = data[data[col1] != '']

Now, the above works as expected when testing locally on windows (via VS Code), however, when I deploy it to Azure Function Apps, the code breaks without an error (I have tried to get one without luck).
The only problem I could foresee happening is that Function App uses Linux to run the code, and I found that Linux uses \n as line terminators rather than \r\n.
Would anyone have any idea as to how I could process these files correctly while still keeping the \n in the column values? Additionally it would be great if I could avoid the funky lstrip post-processing.

Valid CSV would escape the strings, and internal newlines would not be a problem. Can you be explicit and provide a way to set up an exact example (as code) of the windows and linux types of inputs?

There is a way to get the error message: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1262#issuecomment-2119241515

Not really applicable, I can see the funcion, I can trigger it, when I do, the only error I get is that the function failed, even a try/catch block on that particular line doesn't produce any results, which is just weird.

"It would be great if I could avoid the funky lstrip post-processing"
For this you could replace the \r\n by \r before passing the string to StringIO:
import csv

file_content_binary = 'col1\tcol2\tcol3\r\n1\tthis is a place for some text\t50\r\n2\tthis is some other \n text\t100\r\n3\tand finally \n a bit more \n text\t150\r\n'.encode('utf-8')

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str(file_content_binary, 'utf-8').replace('\r\n', '\r')),
                 sep='\t', lineterminator='\r', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

Output:
   col1                               col2  col3
0     1      this is a place for some text    50
1     2         this is some other \n text   100
2     3  and finally \n a bit more \n text   150

Regarding the main question, if you have \n both as line terminators and as internal characters in the strings, there is really not way to programmatically determine which is which and to correctly parse the file, unless you can find another indicator that could help your identify the first field (e.g. another special character).

Thanks, I was hoping that someone might have had a similar issue and that there is an elegant, brilliant workaround. The replace wouldn't work on linux as I believe it doesn't have the \r, so by default it parses line terminators as \n. Guess I'll wait for a bit longer and see if someone comes up with something.
